# Call Virtuemart methods from external script

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I want to call virtuemart methods from external script.How can I do that? 
for example I want to call store() method of a model,how can I do that from an external php file? Thanks
I've already done that.I have done successfully upto here,

```
$user = new JUser;
if(!$user->bind($data)) {
  $status = $user->getError();
}
if (!$user->save()) {
  $status = $user->getError();
}
else {
 $status = "Success";
}
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'tables');
$vuser = new VirtueMartModelUser('0');
var_dump($vuser);
$r = $vuser->store($mdata,TRUE);
```

But I tried to use some methods of Virtuemart,but currently unsuccessful.I dont know how to do that correctly.I'm getting this as blank page.

Comment: Have you tried writing any of your own code yet? You will have to firstly import the Joomla API

Comment: I've already done that.I have done successfully upto here,
$user = new JUser;
if(!$user->bind($data)) {
 $status = $user->getError();
}
if (!$user->save()) {
 $status = $user->getError();
}
else {
  $status = "Success";
}
But I tried to use some methods of Virtuemart,but currently unsuccessful.I dont know how to do that correctly.

Comment: Please add you code to your question, not as a comment as it's hard to read